# MVC view redirection with request parameter passed

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller

I have really weird proposal. I am working on "legacy" application. Form submitting is not handled via ajax but just sent to another view. I need to handle errors that happens on back-end but they just really dont want anything to be changed to REST.

I came this far. Imagine that form is sent to frontend to view. This is backend http controller.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/some/route", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editProfile(@ModelAttribute("model") @Validated Model model,
            BindingResult result,
            Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModalAndView();
    ...
    try{
       someFunctionCall()
       ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
       mav.setViewName("redirect:anotherView?error="+e.getMessage());
       return mav;
    }
    mav.setViewName("redirect:anotherView");
    return mav;
}
```

Another view is same but only i can imagine is to check for error in url params. Since they want error text be then displayed on that view i need to pass it.

in JSP i want to assign it

```
var errorMsg = "${error}";
```

but it looks like JS has problem with format of that string

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
 Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 6706] [SQLState HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character.
 SQL: {CALL P_someMapper_someFnc(...)}
 Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 6706] [SQLState HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character.
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [HY000]; error code [6706]; [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 6706] [SQLState HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.12] [Error 6706] [SQLState HY000] The string contains an untranslatable character.);
```

this is in developer console and throws this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I know this is really bad approach but i need to deal with it. And i am not the really experienced Java guy. But can anybody advice me what is the best solution without using REST and still be able to handle errors from **$(form).submit**?

Thanks in advance

## UPDATE

I forgot the code from "anotherView" and how am i handling it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "anotherView", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView listProfiles..., HttpServletRequest req) {
        String error = req.getParameter("error");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        
        if (error != null && !error.isEmpty()) {
            mav.addObject("error", error);
        }
        mav.setViewName("whatever");
        return mav;
}
```

And in view whatever ther is that js in jsp file

Answer (score 0):

ok, what you need is flash attributes since you are redirecting response to another view,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/some/route", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editProfile(@ModelAttribute("model") @Validated Model model,
        BindingResult result,
        Principal principal,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws JsonProcessingException {
ModelAndView mav = new ModalAndView();
...
try{
   someFunctionCall()
   ...
} catch(Exception e) {
   mav.setViewName("redirect:anotherView");
   redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
   return mav;
}
mav.setViewName("redirect:anotherView");
return mav;
```

}

*i have updated the code since you have updated the question.

Comment: sorry it was only as i wrote fast and removed specific view names and functions. I edited the code. Problem is that error code is there. But i am not able to parse it somehow.

Comment: put is not valid method for ModelAndView class

Comment: yes, sorry. I changed it at the last minute, addObject() is what you should use. plese check my answer again.

Comment: Still the same. But i am receiving error in "anotherView". String error = req.getParameter("error"); this gives me value

Comment: please ask the question clearly and add all necessary code sections for us to understand, check my answer now. I have update it since you changed the question.

Comment: I have accessible error in redirected view. I was getting just error when i sent it within another view and wanted to access in JSP (because of "complexity" of string ? i guess), wasnt able to assign it to js variable

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Actually, i solved it by adding it to hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" id="error-msg" value="${error}" />
```

It looks like it is only some parsing error when i tried to assign it to JS variable simply with

```
var error = '<c:out value="${error}"/>';
```

or

```
var error = "${error}"
```

But hidden input approach works and then value from document.getElementById('error-msg).value is good to go.